# gh-pages branch not making with npm install --save gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, git, github, demo

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to add the React project to the github page to see the demo, and I do the creation steps in the following order, but the gh-pages branch is not created in my github, and it does not show any errors, and I only have the master branch, and I cannot create the demo, thank you. Please guide me.

1- After creating the cartshop repository and finishing the project, I added it to my GitHub

2- npm install gh-pages --save-dev

3- Add the following changes to the package.json folder

"homepage": "https://ZohreScript.github.io/ShopCart",

"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",

4- git remote add origin https://github.com/ZohreScript/ShopCart.git

5-
npm run deploy

6- According to the picture above, I go to the Pages page and only master is displayed in the deploy branch section

Please help, thank you
https://github.com/ZohreScript/ShopCart/settings/pages

and donot show any thing
https://zohrescript.github.io/ShopCart/